# Zeit Now CLI shows no such file or directory

Tags: jekyll, vercel

So i deploying my website with Zeit Now, i deployed in Zeit Now website. I want using CLI to deploying my Jekyll website, but the `now` command shows no such file or directory (i used Indonesian language):

```sh
root@localhost:~/betaleapofazzamgithubio# now init jekyll
bash: /usr/local/bin/now: Tidak ada berkas atau direktori seperti itu
root@localhost:~/betaleapofazzamgithubio# now
bash: /usr/local/bin/now: Tidak ada berkas atau direktori seperti itu
```

Please the help to fix this problem

Comment: This should be fixed as of now@14.1 https://github.com/zeit/now/pull/1922

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed this with `hash -r` and `alias now='node /usr/bin/now` command, but i get other problem:

```sh
root@localhost:~/betaleapofazzamgithubio# now
/usr/bin/now:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ELF
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```